# How to compose to methods, without duplicate input arguments

Tags: scala

Suppose I have two methods

```
scala> def a(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int) : Int = …
a: (a: Int, b: Int, c: Int)Int

scala> def b(i: Int) : Int = …
b: (i: Int)Int
```

How to define a method `c`, that is the composition of both ?
Unfortunately, the following code doen't compile :

```
def c = b(a)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Scalaz defines `Functor` instances for higher-arity functions, so you can just write

```
(a _).map(b)
```

Answer (score 10):

You could convert method `a` to function and then use method `andThen` like this:

```
def a(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int) : Int = a + b + c
def b(i: Int) : Int = i * 2

val c = (a _).tupled andThen b

c(1, 1, 1)
// 6
```

Note that I have to convert function `(Int, Int, Int) => Int` to tupled version - `((Int, Int, Int)) => Int` - here to use `andThen`. So result function `c` accepts `Tuple3` as argument.

You could convert `c` to untupled version (`(Int, Int, Int) => Int`) using `Function.untupled`:

```
val untupledC = Function.untupled(c)

untupledC(1, 1, 1)
// 6
```

#### shapeless

There is no `untupled` method for function arity > 5.

You could also use [`shapeless`](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) `toProduct`/`fromProduct` methods for any arity like this:

```
import shapeless.ops.function._
import shapeless.ops.function._

val c = (a _).toProduct.andThen(b).fromProduct
```