# Compilation error using Scalaz Functor for 7-arity function

Tags: scala, scalaz

I try to implement [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21588082/how-to-compose-to-methods-without-duplicate-input-arguments) and I encounter a compilation error :

```
def $match(o: DBObject) = MongoDBObject("$match" -> o)

def getObj(instance   : String,                   contextValue: Option[SpaceId]           = None,
            eventType  : Option[String]    = None,
           sourceValue: Option[Long]      = None, targetValues: Option[Iterable[Long]] = None,
           startDate  : Option[LocalDate] = None, endDate     : Option[LocalDate]      = None) : DBObject = {

…  
}

def getMatchObj = (getObj _).map($match)
```

And the error is :

```
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /mnt/data/backup/dev/projects/bluekarma/bluekarma-  analytics-scala-play2/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[error] /mnt/data/backup/dev/projects/bluekarma/bluekarma-analytics-scala-play2/app/models/Dao.scala:121: Unable to unapply type `(String, Option[modelsIds.SpaceId],   Option[String], Option[Long], Option[Iterable[Long]], Option[org.joda.time.LocalDate], Option[org.joda.time.LocalDate]) => com.mongodb.casbah.query.Imports.DBObject` into a type constructor of kind `M[_]` that is classified by the type class `scalaz.Functor`
[error] 1) Check that the type class is defined by compiling `implicitly[scalaz.Functor[<type constructor>]]`.
[error] 2) Review the implicits in object Unapply, which only cover common type 'shapes'
[error] (implicit not found: scalaz.Unapply[scalaz.Functor, (String, Option[modelsIds.SpaceId], Option[String], Option[Long], Option[Iterable[Long]], Option[org.joda.time.LocalDate], Option[org.joda.time.LocalDate]) => com.mongodb.casbah.query.Imports.DBObject])
[error]   def getMatchObj = (getObj _).map($match)
[error]                      ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed Feb 6, 2014 9:53:13 AM
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it's a problem with scala compiler: it can't use `Function7[...., T]` as `M[T]`.

You could help to compiler this way:

```
type MF7[T] = (String, Option[SpaceId], Option[String], Option[Long], Option[Iterable[Long]], Option[LocalDate],  Option[LocalDate]) => T

(getObj _: MF7[DBObject]).map(myMatch)
```

Note that you should avoid `$` in names. `$` is widely used in scala for generated names.

`map` works for `Function6`, so you could just reduce parameters cont. For instance you could group parameters using `case class`:

```
case class Period(startDate: Option[LocalDate] = None, endDate: Option[LocalDate] = None)

def getObj(instance: String, contextValue: Option[SpaceId] = None,
           eventType: Option[String] = None, sourceValue: Option[Long] = None,
           targetValues: Option[Iterable[Long]] = None,
           period: Option[Period] = None) : DBObject = ???

val getMatchObj = (getObj _).map(myMatch)
```

#### shapeless

With [`shapeless`](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) you could convert function of any arity to function of single `HList` argument and vice versa:

```
val getMatchObj = (getObj _).toProduct.andThen(myMatch).fromProduct
```

#### Default parameters

`scala` functions can't have default parameters, so the only way to preserve default parameters is to extract all parameters to `case class` like this:

```
case class GetObjArgs(instance: String, contextValue: Option[SpaceId] = None,
               eventType: Option[String] = None, sourceValue: Option[Long] = None,
               targetValues: Option[Iterable[Long]] = None,
               startDate: Option[LocalDate] = None, endDate: Option[LocalDate] = None)

def getObj(a: GetObjArgs): DBObject = ???

val getMatchObj = (getObj _) andThen myMatch

getMatchObj(GetObjArgs("inst", sourceValue = Some(1)))
```

Comment: I use $ to mimic the Casbah query DSL

Comment: Your workaround doesn't work because some arguments are optional : [error] Unspecified value parameters v4, v5, v6, ...

Comment: Period case class is erroneous because both dates are optional

Comment: @YannMoisan: You can't have default parameters for function. See update.

Comment: @YannMoisan: `period` is just an illustration. `startDate = period.flatMap{_.startDate}`, `endDate = period.flatMap{_.endDate}`